# iphone recent calls list does not show contacts

Tags: contacts, iphone

My contacts app seems to be working fine.  But when I go into Phone -> Recents, it shows the full phone numbers of all recent calls instead of labeling by contact.  Even worse, if I tap the `i` information icon to the right of any of the calls, the phone app simply closes.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Likely it's a region thing, try entering your contacts in [international format](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-format-phone-numbers-to-work-internationally) or +[country code][phone number]. Or adjust your region: Settings>General>Language and Region

Comment: My language and region settings are correct.  As of a week or two ago, everything else was working too.  I shouldn't have to go back and edit my contacts.  They used to all work, and now none of them do.  In addition, the contacts app itself is fine.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the very relevant detail that it sudden stopped working a few weeks ago.  I would also include information on where you are in the world, what you region setting is, and what carrier you use.  In this case all are very relevant since phone number format and length vary greatly around the world.  Since there is no recent iOS update released I suspect at this point that you carrier made a change to the way they are providing caller id data.

Comment: Nice points @Tyson.  As it turned out my phone mysteriously fixed itself just hours after I posted the question.  There was no visible software update.  My carrier is AT&T.

Comment: My carrier is AT&T also, I've had no problems.  Did you reset or restart your phone by chance?

Comment: After posting my question, I restarted the phone.  Maybe that was a factor, it did not fix the problem immediately.